# OpenCV 3.0, how to train your cascade

Tags: opencv, cascade, haar-classifier

I want create a road signal classificator, i use 4 road signal (Stop, turn left, turn right and roundabout), i read a lot of guide for build a good classifier (http://note.sonots.com/SciSoftware/haartraining.html, http://www.memememememememe.me/training-haar-cascades/) all of this use a old version of OpenCV and when i try to follow it some passage don't work.
Then i try to create a classifier based on a single image.

```
opencv_createsamples -img NuovoTest1701\Rotatoria\Nuovacartella\greyscale\rotat1.bmp -bg negatives.txt -info cropped2.txt -num 1000 -w 35 -h 35
```

this is one of this for example.
Then i train the cascade with

```
opencv_traincascade -data classifier -vec cropped2.vec -bg negative.txt -numPos 800 -numNeg 350 -numStages 20 -precalcValBufSize 1024 -precalcIdxBufSize 1024 -featureType HAAR -minHitRate 0.995 -maxFalseAlarmRate 0.5 -w 35 -h 35
```

But when i use the file .xml on my app for classifier the object don't work well.
There is a better way to train my classifier? Can someone help me? Thanks a lot.

Comment: `opencv_traincascade` is for object recognition, that is, to recognize a class of objects with similar appearance (like face, human,...) in a picture. That said, the stop sign is significantly different from the other signs. You may use one classifier to recognize stop signs and some other classifiers for the other signs.

Comment: Yes i have create 4 classifier, one for road signal, i use an image like this [link] https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/dc/Italian_traffic_signs_-_old_-_rotatoria.svg [/link] but when i try to detect a real sign don't work well. I don't know if the error it's on the training or in my sample.